# I want show some item on right side in Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
 <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

  <nav class="nav-menu d-flex align-items-center">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i> SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
        
    </ul>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> login</a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```

this is my code and i want to show signup and login on right side

Answer (score 1):

I've added `w-100` to expand the `nav` to fit the entire container, then `justify-content-between`, which positions the children with all space between eachother...

```
 <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

  <nav class="nav-menu d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>         
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i> SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> login</a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here's a pen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/gOgJeJZ

Answer (score 0):

With only CSS you can use `:last-child` selector

```css
ul {
  display:none;
}

ul:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

  <nav class="nav-menu d-flex align-items-center">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i> SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
        
    </ul>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user"></i> login</a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `float:right;` css rule

```
 <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

  <nav class="nav-menu d-flex align-items-center">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i> SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
        
    </ul>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user" style="float:right"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-user" style="float:right"></i> login</a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```